# Math equation in non italic font

Tags: math-mode, italic

I am trying to write the following `$T_E$` but it appears in italic font. I tried also `$\text{T_E}$` but LaTeX gives me error.

Comment: Do you want all math in upright font or only this specific expression?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

Depending of if you are actually writing math or text:

```
 \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{E}}$ or T\textsubscript{E}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The following examples illustrates several possible solutions.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\testline}{Text $\mathrm{T}_\mathrm{E}$ or $\text{T}_\text{E}$ or $\textup{T}_\textup{E}$ or T\textsubscript E}

\begin{document}

\testline

\itshape\testline

\sffamily\upshape\testline

\itshape\testline

\rmfamily\upshape\bfseries%as before but bold   

\testline

\itshape\testline

\sffamily\upshape\testline

\itshape\testline

\end{document}
```

[image]

Observe that some of them adopt the style and font of the text.

Comment: I'd rather use `\mathrm`

Comment: It works!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Gina: Just out of curiosity:  must all your  capital letters in formulæ be in uprightshape?

Comment: @Gina You are welcome. Please consider to upvote one or both answers and accept one of the two.

Answer (score 3):

### With the Modern Toolchain

With the `unicode-math` package (which I personally recommend, although not everyone agrees), `\mathrm` is still supported for backwards compatibility, but so is the synonym `\mathup`, and the closely-related `\symup`.

If you use `\symup`, you can specify a different upright font from the regular text font, and from operator names like `log`, `sin` and `lim`.  My go-to example is setting Euler’s identity in ISO style, that is, with symbolic constants set in an upright font, with the constants e, π and i in Euler and everything else in Palatino.  It’s a good example of why you might want a different upright font for math variables.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}, 
                    bfup/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}},
             script-features={}, sscript-features={}
            ]{Neo Euler}

\newcommand\upe{\symup{e}}
\newcommand\upi{\symup{i}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \upe^{\upi x} &= \cos{x} + \upi \sin{x} \\
  \upe^{\upi \uppi} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: Neo Euler sample]

(If you want to do something like this with the default font, you can try either Latin Modern Roman Unslanted or CMU Serif Upright Italic.  Here’s a sample of the latter:

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek}]{CMU Serif Upright Italic}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \symup{e}^{\symup{i} x} &= \cos{x} + \symup{i} \sin{x} \\
  \symup{e}^{\symup{i \pi}} + 1 &= 0
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: CMU Serif Upright Italic Sample]

The `\symup` command is intended to be used this way.  The `\mathrm` and `\mathup` commands are more for words in equations, like naming variables TIME and ENERGY.  Another good alternative for whole words is to use `\operatorname` from `amsmath`.  This formats the text like `\log` or `\sin`, that is, inserts spacing like 2 log *x* rather than 2logx.

There are similarly `\mathtt` and `\mathsfup` for monospaced and sans-serif letters.

You could also, for example, do `\newcommand\TIME{\mathop{\mbox{\scshape time}}}` to get TIME in small caps, with the spacing of an operator.

You can make upright math variables the default by loading the package with `\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}`.

### With the Legacy Toolchain

The `eulerpx` package implements the popular combination of Euler math variables and Palatino text, along with symbols from `newpxmath`.  If you want upright letters in PDFLaTeX, this in my opinion is the most attractive package for them.

The `cfr-lm` package makes upright italics easily available; with this package, you could write `\DeclareRobusTCommand\mathui[1]{\mbox{\uishape #1}}` to get upright italics.  The example I gave earlier with `\scshape` for small-caps would work as well.

To format a variable name in the default font, `\operatorname` from `amsmath` is a good option.

For a more complicated use case, there are `\DeclareMathAlphabet` and `\DeclareMathSymbol`.